# Not able to send Embeds in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**That is my Code :**

```js
   

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.announce'):
        first_embed = discord.Embed(title="Enter announcement", color=0x2bff00)
        msgg = await message.channel.send(embed=first_embed)
        def check(m):
            return m.channel == message.channel
          
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        ann = msg.content
        print(ann)
        time.sleep(10)
        new_embed = discord.Embed(title='Enter Colour(Red, Green, Yellow)', color=0x2bff00)         
  

        await msgg.edit(embed=new_embed)
        def check(m):
            return m.channel == message.channel
          
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        colo = msg.content
        print(colo)


        channel = client.get_channel(733344357884756018)
        if(colo=='Red'):
            coloo = discord.Colour(0xFF0000)
        if(colo == 'Green'):
            coloo = discord.Colour(0x2bff00)
        if(colo == 'Yellow'):
            coloo = discord.Colour(0xFFFF00)

        await channel.send(discord.Embed(title=ann, color=coloo))


client.run('TOKEN')
```

**Unfortuanely When I run the program it gets the input and everything correctly but the output comes out to be :**

> <discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x05B3FBF8>

**What I am trying to achieve :**

> To basically Send embed Announcements in my server cus it looks fancy lol.

**Any help to solve that or Improvements in my code will be greatly appreciated :)**

*Images:*

[My Input in Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJWSB.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mnTq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that you are sending an embed, by using `.send(embed=discord.Embed)`
Here is the updated code -

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.announce'):
        first_embed = discord.Embed(title="Enter announcement", color=0x2bff00)
        msgg = await message.channel.send(embed=first_embed)
        def check(m):
            return m.channel == message.channel
          
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        ann = msg.content
        print(ann)
        time.sleep(10)
        new_embed = discord.Embed(title='Enter Colour(Red, Green, Yellow)', color=0x2bff00)         
  

        await msgg.edit(embed=new_embed)
        def check(m):
            return m.channel == message.channel
          
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        colo = msg.content
        print(colo)


        channel = client.get_channel(733344357884756018)
        if(colo=='Red'):
            coloo = discord.Colour(0xFF0000)
        if(colo == 'Green'):
            coloo = discord.Colour(0x2bff00)
        if(colo == 'Yellow'):
            coloo = discord.Colour(0xFFFF00)

        await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=ann, color=coloo))


client.run('TOKEN')
```